# Non-characters DB password how to connect

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc, database-connection, ollydbg

I was tasked with retrieving lost password to MS Access database that comes with a piece of software.

I tried a tool for that but returned string looks corrupted including "characters" like: n<ژ”n2ˆrک€r” and others that don't seam to be actual characters at all. However the db file is not corrupted because the software that comes with it has no problem getting data from that db.

Am use multi tool to find the password and this result

Password recovery soft:

ollydbg:

[image]

and same result
am found 2 password
clair text : 4.3.5_For_Alathar
and non text : n<ژ”n2ˆrک€r”

How real password and how to connect:

```
<?php
    $dbName = "D:\UwAmp\www\db\user.mdb";
    $password1 = "4.3.5_For_Alathar";
    $password2 = "n<ژ”n2ˆrک€r”";
    $user = "";
    if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
       die("Could not find database file.");
    }

    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Pwd=$password1; ");
   //$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", $user , $password);
    ?>
```

and result:

SQLDriverConnect: -1905 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Not a valid password

Comment: This is likely an encoding mismatch. For example the password was stored as Latin-1 and you try to view it as UTF8. I'd try to paste it in a plain text editor, like Notepad++ and fiddle with the encoding.

Comment: It is also possible that the characters used are non latin. Try parsing it into a tool like https://2cyr.com/decode for example

Comment: note that your password2 has a few non-displayable bytes/characters at the front (the blank rectangles in your screenshot). it could be a salted/hashed/XORed... version of password1 - they are of almost (?) equal lenght

Answer (score 0):

This string it already encoded into `utf-8`

[image]

```
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0018/index.htm


http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm


http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0016/index.htm


http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/001A/index.htm

ژ
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0698/index.htm

”
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201D/index.htm

ک
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/06A9/index.htm

n
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006E/index.htm

r 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0072/index.htm

< 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003c/index.htm

2 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0032/index.htm

ˆ 
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02C6/index.htm

ˮ
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/02EE/index.htm

€
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20AC/index.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

so i need send this char but not same input output string !!!
how to print this string 
n<ژ”n2ˆrک€r”
";

```
echo "orig= n<ژ”n2ˆrک€r”<br>";
```

this output n<Ú˜â€n2Ë†rÚ©â‚¬râ€

not same how to print correct string or sent to database

```
<?php
$password = mb_convert_encoding('&#x18;&#xc;&#x16;&#xc;&#x1a;&#x6e;&#x3c;&#x698;&#x201d;&#x6e;&#x32;&#x2c6;&#x72;&#x6a9;&#x20ac;&#x72;&#x201d;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
echo "orig= n<ژ”n2ˆrک€r”<br>";
echo "pas= ".$password."<br>";
$unicodeChar = '\u0698';
echo json_decode('"'.$unicodeChar.'"');
echo "<br>";
echo mb_convert_encoding("\x20\x1D", 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');

echo "<br>";

echo "<br>";
?>
```